# Http Post Method. Unable to find valid certification path to target

Tags: java, post, ssl-certificate

Trying to grab data from API using the POST method. and its returning

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I've looked into fixing it but all the answers have been very vague, its something to do with `Installcert`, but no where online is there instructions to that. I am unable to figure them out because I'm relatively new at programming. Any help would be very much appreciated

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    URL url = new URL("https://probasketballapi.com/stats/players");
    Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    params.put("api_key", "8Z9zCply76uBnEDF3itvshqJOPd4Rjoe");
    params.put("first_name", "Kevin");
    params.put("last_name", "Durant");

    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }
    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
        System.out.print((char)c);
```